GET http://localhost:5000/api/v1/auth/authCheck 401 (Unauthorized)
I’m trying to make a GET request to http://localhost:5000/api/v1/auth/authCheck from my React frontend, but I keep getting a 401 Unauthorized error.
The backend is written in Node.js with Express, and the authCheck route is protected by a middleware (protectRoute) that checks for a token in the jwt-netflix cookie.
The token is generated in the backend during login and is supposed to be sent with every request.
The same request works fine when I test it in Thunder Client or Postman, but it fails when called from the React frontend using Axios.
Here’s the middleware I’m using in the backend:
import jwt from "jsonwebtoken";
import { User } from "../models/user.models.js";

export const protectRoute = async (req, res, next) => {
    try {
        const token = req.cookies["jwt-netflix"];
        if (!token) {
            return res.status(401).json({ success: false, message: "Token not found" });
        }
        const decoded = jwt.verify(token, process.env.JWT_SECRET);
        const user = await User.findById(decoded.userId).select("-password");
        if (!user) {
            return res.status(401).json({ success: false, message: "Login required" });
        }
        req.user = user;
        next();
    } catch (error) {
        res.status(500).json({ success: false, message: "Internal server error" });
    }
};


In the frontend, I use Zustand and Axios for state management and API calls. Here’s the relevant frontend code:
export const useAuthUser = create((set) => ({
    user: null,
    isCheckingAuth: true,
    authCheck: async () => {
        try {
            const response = await axios.get("http://localhost:5000/api/v1/auth/authCheck", {
                withCredentials: true,
            });
            set({ user: response.data.user, isCheckingAuth: false });
        } catch (err) {
            set({ user: null, isCheckingAuth: false });
            console.error("Error:", err.message);
        }
    },
}));


I’ve already tried:
Adding { withCredentials: true } to the Axios request.
Ensuring the backend has credentials: true in the CORS configuration.
Testing the backend with Thunder Client, where it works as expected.
Expected Behavior:
The backend should validate the cookie and return the user object as it does in Thunder Client.
Actual Behavior:
The frontend request receives a 401 Unauthorized response.
What could be causing this discrepancy between Thunder Client and the frontend?

Are you getting any CORS-related errors in the browser console?

There's two branches in your middleware, where you respond with 401 - which one of those does it go into, "token not found", or "login required"?

can you check the request from your frontend, is the token included or is it missing ?

no iam not getting any cors related issue

in the frontend the token is missing

some more debugging with this right after the axois request from frontend ```console.log("Request sent with cookies:", document.cookie);

